# 2018 Moderator Election Q&A - Question Collection

Tags: discussion, election

Home Improvement Stack Exchange will be hosting an election on [August 27th, 2018](https://diy.stackexchange.com/election/4). In connection with that, we will be holding a Q&A with the candidates. This will be an opportunity for members of the community to pose questions to the candidates on the topic of moderation. Participation is completely voluntary.

Unlike [last election's procedure](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/875/2013-moderator-election-qa-question-collection), this time we will be collecting the questions one week in advance of the actual election nomination phase beginning. This serves both to give the community an advance warning to prepare for nominations, as well as a means for folks to be able to prepare answers for the Q&A before people actually start voting.

> **The purpose of this thread was to collect questions for the questionnaire. The questionnaire is now live, and you may find it [here](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1381/2018-moderator-election-qa-questionnaire).**

Here's how it'll work:

- Until the nomination phase, (so, until Monday, August 27th at 20:00:00Z UTC, or 4:00 pm EDT on the same day, give or take time to arrive for closure), this question will be open to collect potential questions from the users of the site. Post answers to this question containing any questions you would like to ask the candidates. Please only post *one question per answer*.
- We, the Community Team, will be providing a small selection of generic questions. The first two will be guaranteed to be included, the latter ones are if the community doesn't supply enough questions. This will be done in a single post, unlike the prior instruction.
- If your question contains a link, please use the syntax of `[text](link)`, as that will make it easier for transcribing for the finished questionnaire.
- This is a perfect opportunity to voice questions that are specific to your community and issues that you are running into at currently.
- At the start of the nomination phase, the Community Team will select **up to 8 of the top voted questions submitted by the community** provided in this thread, to use in addition to the aforementioned 2 guaranteed questions.
- Once questions have been selected, a new question will be opened to host the actual questionnaire for the candidates, typically containing 10 questions in total.
- This is not the only option that users have for gathering information on candidates. As a community, you are still free to, for example, hold a live chat session with your candidates to ask further questions, or perhaps clarifications from what is provided in the Q&A.

If you have any questions or feedback about this process, feel free to post as a comment here.

Comment: Where's the C wire go and what size breaker for my garage?

Answer (score 7):

- A user posts something that is incredibly dangerous (i.e. [Just nut the wires together](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/100511/why-dont-you-connect-unused-hot-and-neutral-wires-to-complete-the-circuit), but more dangerous that just a tripped breaker). Do you delete it, publicly moderate it, or just leave a comment?
- Is there any subject you feel should not ever be asked about on DIY?

Comment: How to deal with safety, +1. The moderator we're looking to replace taught me how to judge an asker's ability and to answer accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

- How do you deal with questions that have been abandoned by the OP?

Question abandonment is one of the most pernicious issues we face as a site -- many a time, a user (mostly a brand-new user) will post a question that does not provide all the information needed to answer it, and then proceed to not respond to requests for that information.  These "fire and forget" questions clutter the site and invite speculative answers that are at best broad advice, and at worst flat wrong.  Furthermore, we *need* a tone from the top on this -- while a trickle of close votes does flow in, it is perhaps barely sufficient to keep up with new questions, never mind the litter that already exists.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a set of general questions, gathered as very common questions asked every election. As mentioned in the instructions, the first two questions are guaranteed to show up in the Q&A, while the others are if there aren't enough questions (or, if you like one enough, you may split it off as a separate answer for review within the community's 8).

- How would you deal with a user who produced a steady stream of valuable answers, but tends to generate a large number of arguments/flags from comments?
- How would you handle a situation where another mod closed/deleted/etc a question that you feel shouldn't have been?

---

- In your opinion, what do moderators do?
- A diamond will be attached to everything you say and have said in the past, including questions, answers and comments. Everything you will do will be seen under a different light. How do you feel about that?
- In what way do you feel that being a moderator will make you more effective as opposed to simply reaching 10k or 20k rep?